# results in the onslaught of THE (?) data created

Tags: articles, definite-article

In this sentence

> It results in the onslaught of **the** data created by devices.

should I remove "the" before data? or since I'm talking about a kind of data that is created by devices, I should keep *the*?

Comment: Unlike the article before ***onslaught***, the article before ***data*** (AND the article before ***devices***) are both *optional*. But in both the latter cases it's usually more appropriate to include the article if the relevant ***data*** and/or ***devices*** have already been contextually identified (or *referenced*, at least by implication).

Answer (score 1):

I like:
'it results in an onslaught of device created data'

'it launched an onslaught ..'

Comment: I'd at least put a hyphen between *device* and *created*, but this doesn't answer the question at hand.